# Christol's Theorem

Tags: laurent-series, regular-language

Could anyone give me a proof of Christol's theorem which states that a formal Laurent series is algebraic over the field of rational functions (over some finite field) iff it is automatic ?

Answer (score 1):

The proofs of Christol’s theorem given in [1, 2, 3] all suffer from a gap. An erratum has be given by Joost Winter in 2015, see this [link](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/LivreSeries/Joost-Winter-Christol-Theorem.pdf).

[1] J.-P. Allouche and J. O. Shallit, Automatic Sequences – Theory, Applications, Generalizations. Cambridge University Press, 2003.

[2] V. Berthé, Automatic sequences and transcendence. In N. Pytheas Fogg, editor, Substitutions in Dynamics, Combinatorics and Arithmetics, volume 1794 of Lecture Notes in Mathematics, pages 53–80. Springer, 2002.

[3] J. Berstel and C. Reutenauer, Noncommutative Rational Series with Applications. Cambridge University Press, 2011.